# 2009 Cadillac XLR cruse control isn’t working

Tags: cruise-control, cadillac

I’ve changed the brake position sensor to no avail. Fuse is good. The switch is old style on the blinker arm , are those something that gives trouble ? If they are is there any thing I need to know before taking it (switch) out ? Or is there something else I need to check?